React Native UI align with different screen sizes
I am building a react native app and the UI is working as expected with one screensize but not with another.
I am using responsive units exclusivly.
some parts of words and numbers do not appear. I'll add photos.
what could it be?
Here's some of the code for example-
<Text style={[styles.upperText, { color: textColour}]}>Right now in {location}</Text>
      {weather && weather.current ? (
        <Text style={[styles.text, {color: textColour}]}>{Math.round(weather.current.temp_c)}°C</Text>
      ) : (
        <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Loading weather...</Text>
      )}



